# Finding recursive and explicit formulas for the terms of the sequence: $0.5 + i, 0.8 - 0.8i, 1.1 +0.64i, \ldots$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

> Consider the sequence: $0.5 + i, 0.8 - 0.8i, 1.1 +0.64i, \ldots$
>
> 1. What are the next 2 terms of the sequence?
> 2. Write a recursive equation for the sequence
> 3. Write an explicit equation for the sequence

I need help on all of it, but especially (1). I remember that $i=\sqrt{-1}$, but I'm not sure how to figure out the next terms in the sequence.

There seems to be a pattern between the real parts $(.5, .8, 1.1)$ ($+.3$ each time) and imaginary parts $(i, .8i, .64i)$.

I also noticed alternating addition/subtraction signs, but I'm not sure how that comes into play.

Comment: Yup, what J.W. Tanner said.  Not the real part goes up by $0.3$ each term and the real value of the imaginary part squares and changes signs. It's okay to right something like $z_{k+1} = a_{k+1} + b_{k+1} i$ where $a_{k+1} = a_k + 0.3$ and $b_{k+1} = -b_k\cdot |b_k|$.

Comment: Please do not delete a question after receiving an answer. This is disrespectful to the person who has taken the time to answer your question, and disrespectful to future readers who might be interested in your question and its answer.

Answer (score 1):

A possible sequence is as follows:

$$Re(z_i)= Re(z_{i-1})+0.3$$
$$Im(z_i)= -0.8Im(z_{i-1})$$

\begin{align}z_i &= Re(z_i)+iIm(z_i)\\&=Re(z_{i-1})+0.3-0.8i Im(z_{i-1})\\
&=Re(z_{i-1})+iIm(z_{i-1}) + 0.3 -0.8i Im(z_i)-iIm(z_{i-1}) \end{align}

Simplify the last line.

For the explicit form, refer to AP and GP formula.

Comment: this is super helpful but we dont use Re or z or Im, could u clarify?

Comment: The real part and imaginary part, $z_i$ is the $i$-th term of the sequence.